# Can manufactured countertops warp

Tags: kitchen-counters, countertops

I have a friend with a seam in a countertop that has misaligned after about 4 years. It's man made stone but I'm not sure what material. I would like to fix it but I'd like to know more before I try. It looks like the two sections are flat and could be removed and reinstalled but that would involve redoing the sink and backsplash. I would like to know if it's a bad idea to simply shim up the low corner 1/16th of an inch. I don't think it's from the weight of water in the sink, but from a poor leveling job from the start. [image]

Comment: Wow this is way open, a particle board or mdf with laminate, butcher block, quarts /granite or composit counter top all have different issues. Next we could suggest weak framework. Add more info and photos if you have a real issue or just answer your own question as many do to try and add rep.

Comment: Manufactured countertops? As opposed to the ever elusive naturally occurring in the wild countertops ?

Comment: Hey, come on back and let us know what the outcome was! If the answer here helped you out, give it a check mark. If that's not complete, feel free to write up your own answer and check mark that one.

Answer (score -1):

The difference in height can be from 1) bad initial installation, 2) someone sitting on one of the panels, 3) warping of one panel,

1) Leveling two pieces of plastic laminate (Formica, etc.) is mostly an “art” and patience. Yes, the initial installer could have given up after a few tries.

2) Settlement...ugh...I cringe when my teenagers decide to “help” in the kitchen. An easy test to determine if this is the cause is to pry on the two pieces (gently) and see if they move independently from each other.

3) I’d look under the counter and verify that both panels are particle board. We generally use plywood near sink installations. If it is plywood, it could continue warping with additional water splashed on it, change in humidity, etc.

Here’s an article that explains: https://homeguides.sfgate.com/laminate-countertop-put-over-plywood-particleboard-99004.html

Removing and reinstalling the countertops is difficult because the base will be deformed from prying the tops loose. If the problem is truly just a difference in height, (and not that the two panels have twisted, rotated, moved out of “square”, etc.) then I’d try slowly raising one panel with wedges (shims).

Comment: Great answer and I do believe it's a installation problem. But it is an epoxy/concrete type of material. It's not wood based. It's like Caesarstone or something. They do move independently as they are not joined by that bolt setup on wooden counter tops. I don't know how much flex this material will take before it fractures. I've got to lift it pretty hard to get it back in line and I'm not sure if shiming permanently like that is a good idea.